# Send a variable to Global.asax with Ajax

Tags: jquery, global-variables

Id like to send a variable to the global.asax, but when I debug the value of the string is still null

the ajax call is like this:

```
$.post("Global.asax", { strLandCode: LandCode });
```

my code in global.asax looks like this:

```
        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        string strLandcode = Request["strLandCode"];
    }
```

value strLandcode = null

the post ajax call starts when the default page is loaded (it sends the countrycode of the country that first appears)

Comment: You need to study up on how the asp.net application life cycle works. The mental model you have now is gravely flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Global.asax` is an ASP.Net internal file.
You cannot send requests to it.

Comment: can you tell how to make and use a cross page variable ?

Comment: You should create an ASHX handler.

Comment: this is not helpful for what i'm trying to do. I just need to send a variable, so I can get it back in another aspx page; If i send it directly to that page, it give me troubles

Comment: @Thomas: Wrong.  This is helpful for what you're trying to do.  You can set the session variable in an ASHX handler.